# How do I have these two images coded in separate containers in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have two images they actually do not  overlap but I also can't have them into one piece. How do i put them in the two seperate `divs`

Note I do not want to use a  table.[image]

Comment: strange people go on posting down votes without giving the reason

Comment: position:absolute; ? you should set up a jsfiddle BTW

Comment: @Mike - I didn't downvote you but I have no idea what you are asking when you say "make them look feel nice" (it's very subjective).

Comment: ok, I will remove "make them feel nice"

Comment: This is just an example. If you can provide the images, they could be made more "make them feel nice" !

Comment: But actually I have just 2 images and not four

Comment: I know that. It does not matter. It was just to show an example. Maybe you have to slice and dice your images into 4 instead of 2. It depends on the images.

Comment: @Mike : Please use @ so that I get notifications for your messages.

Comment: @Jawad so do you mean when we have such a scenario, we cannot use it that way, we have to segregate the images in such a way that they are four images.

Comment: No. There are many ways you can acheive this. For example. in my given JSFiddle example, you could use the CSS property background-image on the div#image1 and div#image2. That is one way of doing it. Another way is to slice the image 1 into 2 images as image1of1 and image2of1 and than use them for their respective div containers. As I said, It all depends on the images itself firstly and secondly but most importantly, your requirements such as the dimensions of the container divs and if you want ot use CSS background-image property or HTML img Element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now begins the journey of CSS and manipulation of images for the web. Are these the exact shapes of the images or is this a layout example? Post a fiddle if you can.

If I understand you correctly, simple CSS positions (i.e absolute, relative or floating) will do the trick. But to help you in the most effective fashion, a specific use scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: I had made them actually background images and was using float left, but they don't align. I also tried using background position

Answer (score 0):

If the layout or div that is housing these images is fixed size why not just make them a single image use as background then put your content divs inside the main div.

With a little more information about what you are looking for I can put together a sample.